# Why does this slice not return first 3 elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def print_rangoli(size):
    alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
        print(alp[size-1:i:-1])
        

print_rangoli(3)
```

This prints:

```
c
cb
```

But I want it to print:

```
c
cb
cba
```

I can't seem to access `alp[0]`

Comment: No it prints firstly empty string, that's the point.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Why?

Comment: Because slicing on first iteration returns empty string. Try to play with indexes and you'll find the reason

Comment: just print out the indexes you use in the slice at each stage, and play with them a little in an open shell and see for yourself, it's the best thing you can do to learn

Comment: Because `[size - 1:size - 1:-1]` is a zero size slice.

Comment: @OlvinRoght okay I understand that the first iteration produces a zero size slice sice start and stop indexes are the same but how then can I access the first element in the string?

Comment: @kweks45, `[2:-1:-1]` will return empty string, but `[2::-1]` will return string of first 3 chars reversed. `[2:None:-1]` will do the same. There're several solutions: you can add condition to loop and when `i` equals `0` use another slicing notation; you can print last line outside the loop; you can use short for condition in print.

Comment: If you want solution, here is it: `print(alp[size-1:i-1 if i else None:-1])`. But you should understand the idea behind it

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_rangoli(size):
    alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
        print(alp[i:size][::-1])

print_rangoli(3)
```

it prints

```
c
cb
cba
```

if you want empty print at the first of that, dont do `size - 1` in `range()`

Comment: Good approach, but [a bit less efficient](https://repl.it/@testerreplit/AdequateBigPackages) that one I've offered in comments, because here you're applying slicing twice.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
def print_rangoli(size):
    alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for i in range(size):
      
        print(alp[size-i-1:size][::-1])

print_rangoli(3)
```